# Functions and parameters - is there a better method?

Tags: php

I'm looking at neatening my file structures and code. At the moment I'm making an image gallery, it has a management page which allows the user to upload, edit and delete images/information.

To upload an image, the user would select their files, sumbit the form and arrive at uploaded.php.

To delete an image, the user would click a link taking them to delete.php?id=IMAGEID.

To edit an image, the user would be taken to a page with an editor. Upon making any revisions they'd then be taken to edit.php?id=IMAGEID.

Each page runs either a function. I feel it's unecessary to have three different pages to run three different functions. Is there any way I could neaten this process?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `if` statements in main document and put all texts in every `if` and change all page names to single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it just depends on how you like to manage your files and how you are using your IDE when you've to edit something.

If you're working alone, it's clearly up to you. If you know someone will, maybe, have to rework your code someday, having three files could be a plus, somehow.

I guess you're not concerned about SEO for these pages, but just in case the problem appears again, it could be better to have actions in parameters, rather than in files name.
`/manage.php?edit` or `/manage.php?delete` or `/manage.php?upload`

---

But, if your code is really really big, using three files could still result in a lower use of memory (Well, very slight improvement, but still)

Comment: Yes, I think a single actions page with ?edit, ?delete and ?insert may be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you don't need 3 pages for each function

1)Delete ,instead of redirection the user to a different page and delete it ,you can add an image button which delete icon and when user click on it ,it call a specific function in your php and delete it then refresh your page.

2)Edit and Insert : these are 1 page ,like make your insert page if it doesnt have a query string with the Image ID then it's insert function ,else it contains and ID then load the content of this Image inside your inputs and while saving check if there is ID then update else insert new record

So,you moved from 3 pages to 1 page only.Hope this helped you.